# How to run .desktop files from command line

Tags: command-line, autostart, openbox

I am configuring a box with openbox (with GNOME under the scenes), and I want to run the .desktop files in `/etc/xdg/autostart/` from a script at login.

But `xdg-open` and `gnome-open` do not seem to do what I want (unless I use them in the wrong way).

I am looking for a *standard* command, and don't want to parse the desktop files looking for the `Exec` line.

Also welcome would be an indication on how to tell `openbox` to start those desktop files in some other way, and without an *ad hoc* script.